# OANDA:XAUUSD - Base currency is empty

Tags: pine-script

The title is pretty self explanatory. When I open OANDA:XAUUSD and then print the base currency, it doesn't display XAU, but instead it's empty.

```
//@version=4
study("Base currency issue - StackOverflow", overlay = true)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index + 50, close, str.format("Base currency: {0} | Quote currency: {1}", syminfo.basecurrency, syminfo.currency))
```

The reason I need it is because I'm developing a risk management indicator, which needs to calculate the Pip Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syminfo.basecurrency will only return the first currency in a forex pair, or the first coin for a crypto pair. When using syminfo.type youll see that it returns CFD as XAU is not a currency, but a commodity. You could try starting with this function if you're looking for pip size:

```
GetPipSize() =>
    syminfo.mintick * (syminfo.type == "forex" ? 10 : 1)
```

Cheers

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the `Pip Value to the dollar` for the risk management. `Pip Value = (One Pip / Exchange Rate) * Lot Size`